# How to use linear indexing with rows traversal instead columns in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 2d matrix, i want to traverse all elements in this matrix something like this:

```
a = 
0  1  2
5  4  3
6  7  8

for i = 1 : 81
    a(i) = ....
....
```

now, for example when i use `a(2)`, i received "5", but i want `a(2)` give me "1". in the other word, i want use linear indexing with rows traversal instead of columns.

Comment: Do you really want a row oriented linear index that ALSO has a switchback order as shown???? Or is this simply a request for a simple row order linear index, and you screwed up your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To traverse an array down rows try something like this. Here `a` has `col_count` columns and `row_count` rows

```
for j = 1:col_count
   for i=1:row_count
       a(i,j)       %# display element at row i, column j
   end
end
```

This will print out your elements in turn starting with first column, printing element of each row in that column in row order. This is repeated for each column.

**edit**: If you must use a single index then just use your current single index notation, but act on the transpose of your matrix:

```
 b = a.'
 for i = 1:size
     b(i)     
 end
```

Comment: thanks mathematician1975, but i must use a single loop and single index like a(2)

Comment: @mathematician1975: I suggest, to use the `.'` operator as the hyphen conjugates the matrix, which is not wanted in this case.

Comment: @Mehrwolf Hmm it appears that someone else has modified my answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is column major, so linear indexing will always traverse by columns first.  But, you can easily get the effect you want by transposing the matrix so columns and rows are reversed.

Comment: Um, not if the scan is a switchback scheme as shown by the question.

Comment: I noticed the ordering too, but he asked for row traversal so I opted to not read anything into it.  Looks like it wasn't part of the question.